# How to add CSS to HTML helpers ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper

I have a HTML helper like this:

```
<p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameUser)</p>
```

this is when the code run :

[image]

How do I apply a CSS class to it? like i want the input background is blue or border radius 15px

Comment: `.EditorFor()` is meant for RAD, not for fine-control over the generated HTML. As an alternative, apply the class to the outer `<p>` and use that in your selectors, e.g. `<p class="nameUserField">` with `p.nameUserField input[type=text] { border: 5px solid rebeccapurple; }`

Answer (score 0):

there are three ways for adding css in html
1.) inline CSS eg:
2.) internal CSS eg:  under this tag you can use CSS properties
3.) external CSS - create a new file with .CSS extension and then link html and CSS file using LINKREL property.``

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).